# Downloaded typesafe2.0 with play framework, get exception on web request

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

Downloaded typesafe 2.0 with Play 2 (2.0RC3)

Ran g8 typesafehub/play-scala also g8 typesafehub/play-java (both do the same)

All ok, then sbt run

All looks ok, comes up on port 9000. But when I go to web page I get an exception:

```
[error] {file:/C:/typesafe2/my_app_scala/}my_app_scala/compile:sources: java.lan
g.ExceptionInInitializerError
[error] application -

! Internal server error, for request [GET /] ->

play.api.UnexpectedException: Unexpected exception [ExceptionInInitializerError:
 null]
        at sbt.PlayReloader$$anon$2$$anonfun$reload$3$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$
11.apply(PlayReloader.scala:228) ~[na:na]
        at sbt.PlayReloader$$anon$2$$anonfun$reload$3$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$
11.apply(PlayReloader.scala:221) ~[na:na]
        at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:133) ~[scala-library.jar:0.11.2]
        at sbt.PlayReloader$$anon$2$$anonfun$reload$3$$anonfun$2.apply(PlayReloa
der.scala:221) ~[na:na]
        at sbt.PlayReloader$$anon$2$$anonfun$reload$3$$anonfun$2.apply(PlayReloa
der.scala:219) ~[na:na]
        at scala.Either$LeftProjection.map(Either.scala:183) ~[scala-library.jar
:0.11.2]
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
        at play.templates.ScalaTemplateCompiler$TemplateAsFunctionCompiler$.getF
unctionMapping(ScalaTemplates.scala:561) ~[templates_2.9.1-2.0-RC3.jar:2.0-RC3]
        at play.templates.ScalaTemplateCompiler$.generateFinalTemplate(ScalaTemp
lates.scala:500) ~[templates_2.9.1-2.0-RC3.jar:2.0-RC3]
        at play.templates.ScalaTemplateCompiler$.compile(ScalaTemplates.scala:18
9) ~[templates_2.9.1-2.0-RC3.jar:2.0-RC3]
        at sbt.PlayCommands$$anonfun$48$$anonfun$apply$38.apply(PlayCommands.sca
la:533) ~[na:na]
        at sbt.PlayCommands$$anonfun$48$$anonfun$apply$38.apply(PlayCommands.sca
la:531) ~[na:na]
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.
scala:60) ~[scala-library.jar:0.11.2]
Caused by: scala.tools.nsc.MissingRequirementError: object scala not found.
        at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.Definitions$definitions$.getModuleOrClass(Defi
nitions.scala:655) ~[scala-compiler.jar:na]
        at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.Definitions$definitions$.getModule(Definitions
.scala:605) ~[scala-compiler.jar:na]
        at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.Definitions$definitions$.ScalaPackage(Definiti
ons.scala:145) ~[scala-compiler.jar:na]
        at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.Definitions$definitions$.ScalaPackageClass(Def
initions.scala:146) ~[scala-compiler.jar:na]
        at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.Definitions$definitions$.AnyClass(Definitions.
scala:176) ~[scala-compiler.jar:na]
        at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.Definitions$definitions$.init(Definitions.scal
a:814) ~[scala-compiler.jar:na]
```

Any idea? Scala seems fine in that I can g8 typesafehub/scala-sbt and g8 typesafehub/akka-scala-sbt with no problem

Thanks.

Comment: Would this be better served by logging an issue against the project?

Comment: Here's the underlying project to report issues against: https://github.com/typesafehub/play-scala.g8/issues

Comment: Funny, I've just got exactly the same problem. It's a shame this question was closed because it is "unlikely to ever help any future visitors".

Comment: Yes, felt it a bit arrogant to me too. Shame having something as useful as stackoverflow and then people acting as police deciding what is a useful question. If you find out then please tell me. It was never important enough for me to chase this further after having this mercilessly closed down, just curious and wanted to flag up for others, such as yourself. Wonder if the po po will unclose it?

Comment: I had the same error for a new created scala play project. After 'sbt compile' in the project directory it went fine.

Comment: This question should not have been closed IMO. I can reproduce the problem on Win XP from the current typeface download stack.

Comment: I have the same problem.  Wish this question wasn't closed.

Comment: Same here on OS-X.  Can we petition to re-open the question?