# "object scala not found" trying to run vanilla Play 2 app

Tags: playframework, classpath, sbt, playframework-2.0

I am tearing my hair out trying to get a vanilla Play app running on my Windows (but not for much longer, hopefully!) dev machine.

I downloaded the typesafe-stack 2.1 and created a basic Play application using the recommended giterate template:

`g8 typesafehub/play-scala`.

I then ran `sbt run` and wait for the server to start, navigate to `localhost:9000` and get a `java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError` with root cause `MissingRequirementError: object scala not found`.

Sounds like a classpath issue (?) - but I have no idea where to start as 1) I'm new to sbt, scala, and play, and 2) I'm rubbish at diagnosing and fixing classpath issues. So I thought I would ask here, hoping that someone might be able to point me in a useful directoion of investigation.

Here is the stacktrace:

```
play.api.UnexpectedException: Unexpected exception [ExceptionInInitializerError: null]
        at sbt.PlayReloader$$anon$2$$anonfun$reload$3$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$11.apply(PlayReloader.scala:228) ~[na:na]
        at sbt.PlayReloader$$anon$2$$anonfun$reload$3$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$11.apply(PlayReloader.scala:221) ~[na:na]
        at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:133) ~[scala-library.jar:0.11.2]
        at sbt.PlayReloader$$anon$2$$anonfun$reload$3$$anonfun$2.apply(PlayReloader.scala:221) ~[na:na]
        at sbt.PlayReloader$$anon$2$$anonfun$reload$3$$anonfun$2.apply(PlayReloader.scala:219) ~[na:na]
        at scala.Either$LeftProjection.map(Either.scala:183) ~[scala-library.jar:0.11.2]
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
        at play.templates.ScalaTemplateCompiler$TemplateAsFunctionCompiler$.getFunctionMapping(ScalaTemplates.scala:561) ~[templates_2.9.1-2.0.jar:2.0]
        at play.templates.ScalaTemplateCompiler$.generateFinalTemplate(ScalaTemplates.scala:500) ~[templates_2.9.1-2.0.jar:2.0]
        at play.templates.ScalaTemplateCompiler$.compile(ScalaTemplates.scala:189) ~[templates_2.9.1-2.0.jar:2.0]
        at sbt.PlayCommands$$anonfun$48$$anonfun$apply$38.apply(PlayCommands.scala:533) ~[na:na]
        at sbt.PlayCommands$$anonfun$48$$anonfun$apply$38.apply(PlayCommands.scala:531) ~[na:na]
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:60) ~[scala-library.jar:0.11.2]
Caused by: scala.tools.nsc.MissingRequirementError: object scala not found.
        at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.Definitions$definitions$.getModuleOrClass(Definitions.scala:655) ~[scala-compiler.jar:na]
        at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.Definitions$definitions$.getModule(Definitions.scala:605) ~[scala-compiler.jar:na]
        at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.Definitions$definitions$.ScalaPackage(Definitions.scala:145) ~[scala-compiler.jar:na]
        at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.Definitions$definitions$.ScalaPackageClass(Definitions.scala:146) ~[scala-compiler.jar:na]
        at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.Definitions$definitions$.AnyClass(Definitions.scala:176) ~[scala-compiler.jar:na]
        at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.Definitions$definitions$.init(Definitions.scala:814) ~[scala-compiler.jar:na]
```

Note: someone else has already asked exactly the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9700689/586748), but it was closed as something that is "is unlikely to ever help any future visitors". As I am a future visitor, who would find an answer to it very helpful, I felt justified in asking it again myself.

Thanks!

Comment: I have the same exact problem.  Please do not close this one as unlikely to help another person.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not the first person I've heard of complaining when installing Play 2.0 via the Typesafe Stack. I haven't had any time to investigate it myself, but I know first hand that installing Play 2.0 via the [Play 2.0 Documentation](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/Installing) should circumvent the issue above.

The other thought I have is that you are issuing `sbt` instead of `play`. Granted, they are almost the same application, but I would expect your `sbt` command is pointing to an instance of `sbt`, while `play` is likely to point to a separate executable with a different class path.

Comment: Indeed, in my first tut for play2 I did not used set but onlyplay command. Further I found the docs on GitHub more useful then on play's website...

Comment: The problem is that typesafe's docs explicitly show using sbt.  And when I installed the typesafe stack, it did not install Play in such a way that I can just type play at a command line and have it work.

Comment: I did eventually get it to work by abandoning the typesafe stack. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, I found myself having a similar problem using play 2.0.4 in combination with eclipse.

I solved the issue by adding

```
  <classpathentry path="<myProjectDirectory>\target\scala-2.9.1\classes_managed" kind="lib"></classpathentry>
```

to `<myProjectDirectory>/.classpath`

I don't know how, but somehow this line got removed...